# iTextSharp - Populating a dynamic table field

Tags: c#, itext

I have an XDP and a Dynamic PDF file with dynamic fields.

I am able to fill out the text fields and alike (as shown in the code below).

The issue is that I have a dynamic table field and I am not sure how to populate it. I found many nice tutorials to create a table "from scratch", but here the table is a field already predefined (width, number of columns, etc.)

How could I populate a dynamic table field? Any help will be much appreciated.

PS - Here is the code I am using to populate text fields and alike, based on this article: http://bit.ly/12Xu1QY

```
string template = "template.pdf";
string new = "new.pdf";

var reader = new PdfReader(template);
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create));

AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

fields.SetField("FIELD_NAME_1", "VALUE1");
fields.SetField("FIELD_NAME_2", "VALUE2");

stamper.Close();
```

**EDIT:**

Judging from @Bruno Lowagie answer, I am afraid I didn't use the correct wording. I have a LiveCycle Designer File (XDP) and I save it as a Dynamic PDF Form File (PDF). This is coming from an SAP application. The code above worked nicely for me, so I am understanding it is actually a static PDF form.

Then, the table field is called "FIELD" - I will need a way to populate the rows.

I'm sorry for the confusion and appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Special thanks to @Bruno Lowagie for pointing me to the right direction.

Now I will reproduce the solution.

I started out with an XDP file (Adobe LiveCycle file) with XFA forms. I then saved it to a PDF file, and filled out the forms with Acrobat Pro, and finally exported the form data to an XML file.

This is eventually the XML file that I fed the `PdfStamper` with, in order to populate the PDF file.

So first I dynamically generated the XML in this way:

```
var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", ""),
new XElement("CUSTOMER",
new XElement("FIRST_NAME", FirstNameTextBox.Text),
new XElement("LAST_NAME", LastNameTextBox.Text)
));
```

And then I fed it to the `PdfStamper` in this way:

```
var reader = new PdfReader(templateFilename);
var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(bolFilename, FileMode.Create));
var xml = GenerateXml(); // Above code
var stream = new MemoryStream(UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml ?? String.Empty));

stamper.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(stream);
stamper.Close();
```

(Don't forget to put the code within a using statement.)

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up two different technologies.

The article you're referring to fills out a static form. That is: either a PDF containing nothing but AcroForm fields, or a hybrid form consisting of a definition of the form based on **AcroForm technology** *as well as* based on the **XML Forms Architecture** (XFA).

You're talking about a dynamic form, which means you're talking about pure XFA. You need a completely different example: [Java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=165) / [C#](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter08/XfaMovies.cs)

Once you have filled out the form using the `fillXfaForm()` method, you can flatten the form using the closed source [XFA Worker](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xfademo). See also the [download page](http://itextsupport.com/download/xfaworker.html).

Comment: Thank you! I edited my question to elaborate more. I will definitely look into the links. Much appreciated.

Comment: I still don't understand the question. There is no such thing as a "table field" in a static PDF form. In a dynamic PDF form, you can have repeating subforms, meaning that you can repeat a row depending on the data, but a static form is... static. In static forms, you can't define tables that grow automatically depending on the number of records you want to fill in.