# populating dynamic table using itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf

we have the option to design a PDF form in a tool (e.g. Nitro PDF) . for other fields , it seems ok to simply access the Acrofields by name and set the value.

any help will be appreciated to guide how to set a dynamic table field in the pdf and dynamically add rows to it using a library (currently using iTextsharp in C#) .

any help appreciated..

Comment: I did something similar a while ago using SQL Reports and iTextSharp to create dynamic PDFs.  There may be a simpler way of doing this, but if you don't get a good answer let me know and I can post up a starter answer.

Comment: thank you for the reply.. currently awaiting for an answer :)

Comment: This seems a lot more suitable than my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704091/itextsharp-populating-a-dynamic-table-field?rq=1

Comment: thank you for the reply .. currently have shifted to rdlc for populating data related to dynamic tables.. :)